# CSS Making a tab bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility, tabbar

I'm making a tab bar where pressing the appropriate tab button (like the web browsers) shows the appropriate elements by changing the visibility property of each of the elements. But the elements do not appear right under the bar, they appear shifted down if it isn't the first button. This is because visibility doesn't affect layout and the items are written one after another. I want them to all appear at the top. I can't remove them because they have javascript properties, and i cant position absolute them without them not being able to fill their container with w/h 100%. How would  you do this[image: img]

HTML

```
<tab-view id="tabView">
                <tab-bar></tab-bar>

                <tab-content>
                    <!-- First tab-content will show on page load -->
                    <tab-item data-title="Meat Pizzas">
                        <circular-view id="exampleView" data-object-class="exampleObject" data-autoloop-interval="1000 ">
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">0</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">1</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">2</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">3</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">4</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">5</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">6</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">7</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">8</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">9</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">10</circular-object>
                            <!-- Last object in the list is the
                first to be featured on page load -->
                        </circular-view>
                    </tab-item>

                    <tab-item data-title="Second Thing">
                        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:gray;">
                            hi
                        </div>
                    </tab-item>

                    <tab-item data-title="Third Thing">
                        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:gray;">
                            hi
                        </div>
                    </tab-item>
                </tab-content>


            </tab-view>
```

Button press

```
tabViewToBe.tabButtonPressed = function (title) {
            //Deselect all except one that was clicked and show the right item
            for (var a in tabViewToBe.bar.buttons) {
                var wasClicked = $(tabViewToBe.bar.buttons[a]).html() == title,
                    b = tabViewToBe.bar.buttons[a];
                if (wasClicked === false) {
                    b.deselect();
                    $(tabViewToBe.items[a]).css("display", "none"); //Used to be visibility, I was messing around with stuff
                } else {
                    b.select();
                    $(tabViewToBe.items[a]).css("display", "block");
                }
            }
        };
```

More detail:

Sorry, the problem here is that with display, I will have one of the tab-item animating depending on its size. But when `display: none` it cant get the size so when I move back all the objects are in the upper left. I can't remove the objects, and I can't just use visibility

Comment: pls show your code or make a jsfiddle

Comment: I've added the relevant parts of the code

Comment: make a fiddle it will be easy for us to help you out

Comment: Here is a dropbox link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4e6juz9aas2s4t/Website.zip Important files are ExamplePage.html, FrameworkStyles.css,TabView.js

Comment: I just had an idea, I will get the CircularView to reset the position when it appears unless theres a better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using position relative and having negative values for the 2nd, 3rd, etc item to move it to the right place.

Comment: I was putting together a jsfiddle for you, but had to go out, and now you've solved it. You're right with the position relative, but you shouldn't have to use negative values for the 2nd and 3rd items, I don't believe. If you use `display: none;` rather than `visibility:hidden`, that should give you the correct result. The main difference being that your negative value likely depends on the size of the height of the div, and should that height change, you don't want to have to change your code.

Comment: Display none reset the position of the animating pizza thing so if it was halfway through an animation while switching tabs i couldn't reset it without modifying quite a bit of code. the pos relative was much easier

Comment: @pedalpete Hi, I know it's been a while but in Firefox it still pretends something is there with this method. The tab contents visually have moved to the place i want them to but a scrollbar still implies there is stuff below everything else.